# Websphere url mapping

Tags: url, url-rewriting, websphere, httpserver, virtual-hosts

I have an application installed on a WebSphere 8.5 application server which respond to the url: *host_or_ip:9081/Stuff*.

The requirement is that when i call the url  *host_or_ip:9080/Stuff*. the request goes to: *host_or_ip:9081/Stuff* without going back to the client in the process (no redirect)

The host and the context root are the same, the port changes from **9080** to **9081**.

I've thinked about a web server like IHS, but i don't know how to configure it properly. Moreover i've searched for a similar issue online and i found many different ways to do similar things like url rewriting, virtual hosts and http servers.

Which one should i choose and how it works?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why cant you just call 9081 without redirection or serv from 9080? Its a bit strange requirement.

Comment: Because of a security constraint when it is called from the internet.

Comment: It is a constraint that we can't remove. I just want to know if this solution is possible in some way :) thanks

Comment: So just run WebSphere on 9080 if you have that port open. Other solution would be to use IHS and configure it to run on 9080 port and configure WAS to run on 9081. WebSphere Plugin for IHS will automatically route your requests from 9080 to WAS running on 9081 without any redirect. But from security point of view in that case you usually setup IHS on the remote machine on port 80, not same machine on 9080.

Comment: I need to map just the specific url _host_name:9080/Stuff_ to go on the 9081 port not all the calls to the 9080. Is it possible?

Comment: Your requirement is very vague. You really have to describe better what is your problem. Are you having something else listening on 9080 port? (then you have to change configuration of that something, as it is not possible to have two servers listening on the same port and ip).

Comment: You're right sorry i can't explain myself. I have 2 application servers 1 respond to the port 9080 and the other to the 9081.

Comment: The first server has got some application that needs to stay there (port 9080). I can't keep a particular application on that server so i had to move it to the second server (9081) but i want that this application is reachable from the same url on the port 9080 as i explain in the first post.

Comment: If both servers are WebSphere, then change the first server port to something different e.g. 9082, install IHS with Plugin, and configure plugin in such a way that it forwards for /Stuff to 9081 server and rest to the other server. If that other server is not a WebSphere, then you will have to use some kind of other proxy server instead of IHS and plugin.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for the patience :) and sorry again for my poor explaination. I think i will look for other proxy server. Thanks again